# Is there a way to check a single column's values in MUI Data Grid?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have a MUI Data Grid with an editable column called 'Status', which can have three values - "Accepted", "Ready for Review" and "Update Required". OnCellCommit, I would like to be able to check if all rows in the Grid have been marked as "Accepted" and enable a button. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there's anything directly available. The editing API does not seem to give you access to the table, and rows are mostly isolated. You'll probably have to process that on the `rows` outside if the data is controlled.

Answer (score 0):

hey You can try something like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridValueGetterParams } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 90 },
  {
    field: 'firstName',
    headerName: 'First name',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'lastName',
    headerName: 'Last name',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'age',
    headerName: 'Age',
    type: 'number',
    width: 110,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'fullName',
    headerName: 'Full name',
    description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.',
    sortable: false,
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params: GridValueGetterParams) =>
      `${params.row.firstName || ''} ${params.row.lastName || ''}`,
  },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42 },
  { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45 },
  { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16 },
  { id: 5, lastName: 'Targaryen', firstName: 'Daenerys', age: null },
  { id: 6, lastName: 'Melisandre', firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: 'Clifford', firstName: 'Ferrara', age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: 'Frances', firstName: 'Rossini', age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: 'Roxie', firstName: 'Harvey', age: 65 },
];

const singleColumn = (c, r) => {
  const index = c.filter((ele) => {
    console.log(ele.field);
    return ele.field == 'age'; //change the age to your desired feild name
  });
  return r.map((e) => {
    const ele = index[0].field;
    return e[ele];
  });
};

export default function DataGridDemo() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
        experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
      >
        {console.log('gg', singleColumn(columns, rows))}
      </DataGrid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```